# Can't open files passed as args

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, fasm

```
    format ELF

    section '.bss' writeable
    BUFFLEN equ 256
    buff rb BUFFLEN

    section '.data' writeable
    writeCode db 'w',0
    readCode db 'r',0
    printStr db "%d. %s",0

    section '.text' executable
    extrn fopen
    extrn fclose
    extrn fprintf
    extrn fgets
    public main

main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    push ebx
    push esi
    push edi



    mov eax,[ebp+8]
    cmp eax,3
    jne exit
openin:
    push readCode
    push dword[ebp+16]
    call fopen
    add esp,8
    mov esi,eax

openout:
    push writeCode
    push dword[ebp+20]
    call fopen
    add esp,8
    mov edi,eax

read:
    mov ebx,1
.rw:
    push esi
    push BUFFLEN
    push buff
    call fgets
    add esp,12
    cmp eax,0
    je close

    push buff
    push ebx
    push printStr
    push edi
    call fprintf
    add esp,16

    inc ebx
    jmp .rw

close:  
    push esi
    call fclose
    add esp,4

    push edi
    call fclose
    add esp,4



exit:
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

If I pass memory adresses like:
fileIn rb "test1",0. Everything works fine, but when passing filename as arg I get segmentation error. I've tried fullpaths, moving to regs and so on, but nothing helps.
As I thought, I can pass args this way to fopen(), because they are terminated with 0, aren't they? perror() tells that no such file, or directory.

Comment: `argc` is passed as the first parameter to `main` and a **pointer** to an array of string pointers (`argv`) is passed as the second parameter. Your code is working on the false premise that each string pointer is a successive argument on the stack. That is the case if you use `_start` as an entry point when you avoid using the _C_ startup.

Comment: Daaaaaamn, I've forgot this. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in case of C startup you have an array of pointers to your args, nor the longish list of arguments pushed in stack.

P.S. And don't read programming books late night, cause you will remember completely nothing on the morning and will spend whole day figuring out what you've did wrong :)